# How do I Convert an OpenLayers Polygon to a Circle?

Tags: openlayers-5

I have a drawing feature where, as in one case, a person can draw a circle using the methodology in [OL docs example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html?q=draw). When that's saved, the server needed to be have it converted to a polygon, and I was able to do that using [`fromCircle`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html#.fromCircle).

Now, I'm needing to make the circle modifiable after it's been converted and saved. But I don't see a clear cut way to get a Circle geometry out of the Polygon tools provided in the library. There is a [`Polygon.circular`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html#.circular), but that doesn't sound like what I want.

I'm guessing the only way to do this is to grab the center, and one of the segment points, and figure out the radius manually?

Comment: As long as `fromCircle` used sides set to a multiple of 4 and rotation zero (which is the default) center and radius can be easily obtained to covert back to a circle 

           `center = ol.extent.getCenter(polygon.getExtent());
            radius = ol.extent.getWidth(polygon.getExtent())/2;`

Comment: Oh. Nice! Thanks so much. If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll certainly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `fromCircle` used sides set to a multiple of 4 and rotation zero (which are the default) center and radius can be easily obtained to convert back to a circle:

```
 center = ol.extent.getCenter(polygon.getExtent());
 radius = ol.extent.getWidth(polygon.getExtent())/2;
```